# Use the member arrow instead of quoting?

Tags: php, variables

Probably very schoolboy issue, I'd like to use a variable like a member variable instead of in quotes, how'd I go about that?

```
$something->title
```

instead of

```
something("title")
```

I can do the latter with a function but I think it'd be neater and nicer if I could use the former.

Comment: PHP is the desired language

Comment: Something like an instance of StdClass (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)?

Comment: That arrow is rather an object operator. Look for some PHP OOPs tutorial please..

Comment: Are you talking about object?

Comment: OK I think I'm looking to return a value based on a table entry so I might have a settings table and within that I might have site_name so I could just go $settings->site_name then I might have more static settings to do the same with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `->` is a OOP Construct (member operator) in PHP. Create the `$something` as an object and then initialize it:

```
class Something {
  public $title;
}
```

And initialize it this way:

```
$something = new Something;
$something->title = "Whatever";
```

If you wanna initialize during the creation, you can use constructors:

```
class Something {
  public $title;
  public function __construct ($newTitle) {
    $this->title = $newTitle;
  }
}
```

And initialize it this way:

```
$something = new Something("Whatever");
```

---

**In your use case...**

You wanna use it for the settings object. Well, you can "define" settings framework this way:

```
class DataBase {
  private $host;
  private $user;
  // ---
  // ---
  // ---
}

class Settings {
  public $db = new DataBase("host", "user", "pass", "name");
  // ---
  // ---
  // ---
}

$settings = new Settings();
```

And then for individual stuff, you can do something like this:

```
$settings->title
$settings->db->connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use php classes where you define a class and call its properties :

```
class Test
{
  var $title;

  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->title = 'hello';
  }

}

$obj= new Test();
echo $obj->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, perhaps I'm missing the point.

Lets say I have a settings table and it has columns such as id, name, setting and the name column contains lots of general things you might want to set so site_name, date_format, email_address, meta_title etc and those things are adjustable by having a value in the settings column corresponding to the name so I'd like to say...

echo $setting->site_name,
echo $setting->date_format

and such...I understand I should by using a class but for the life of me I can't refer to a table value, I can refer to a column name.

Thank you for the help thus far.